# Refactor Maven project with inheritance and/or aggregation

Tags: java, maven

I've read many questions and answers here on SO, but I can't find an aswer that clears my doubts.

I have a big Java project managed with `Maven` (let's call it **MainProj**), and it has many dependencies, some of which are other *standalone* projects done by me and my team.

What I've done is a single maven project for each related project, installed each one into my repository, and imported into the **MainProj** with standard `<dependency></dependency>` imports.

I've now discovered *inheritance* and *aggregation* in Maven, but what I can't figure out is:

- Is my **MyProject** suitable for this structure, or is the standard dependency import the best practice?
- I've read the concept of **superPom** (or parent pom), but I can't figure how it works: should I create a standalone pom, not related to any java code, that only manages the childs and other related poms? Or that **superPom** should be, in my example, the one included in **MainProj** ?
- In case, should I import my related projects with inheritance or with aggregation?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe read the contents on the [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) site. PS. you can have project inheritance and aggregation together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this issue in two ways.

1) ParentPOM (SuperPOM)

2) Multi Module Maven Project

**Super POM**

Super POM (Parent POM) is used to structure the project to avoid redundancies or duplicate configurations using inheritance between pom files. You have a create a separate project for parent POM and all the common dependencies and plugins should be added. Then in the child project, you have to add the parent POM identifier

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenExamples</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Eg: https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/

**Multi Module Project**

When multiple modules are parts of a project, the preferred approach is to structure them as a maven multi-module project and delegate the build responsibility completely to Maven. It's doesn't require a new project like Super POM. In the multi-module project, you add all the related project to the Main project. The main project POM acts as a top-level POM (same like Super POM) and contains all the common dependencies and plugins.

Eg: http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/

Ref: [How to structure a multi-modules Maven project to compile it at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034544/how-to-structure-a-multi-modules-maven-project-to-compile-it-at-once)