# Is there any way to perform MVN clean install on multiple separate modules in a particular sequence apart from shell script or batch script?

Tags: maven, installation, multi-module, maven-reactor

I have used aggregator POM for that and it says "The reactor contains different versions.
The reactor is not valid
".
Included the aggregator POM file

```
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>moduleA-bom</module>
    <module>module-dependencies</module>
    <module>module-parent</module>
    <module>module-core-datamodel</module>
```

Comment: What are you trying with your version tag? Why not just list the modules in the relevant section and let Maven build them?

Comment: I did that too and created a <modules> tag and defined the <module> inside this. but stll I'm facing the same error

Comment: You cannot have a list of versions in the `<version>` tag. Just one version.

Comment: @JFMeier I did that too ... still same error

Comment: I am trying to perform "mvn clean install" on different modules which have different parents. so I need to create a pom which will perform the action on <module> one by one.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your new POMs (with the correct version tags).

Comment: @JFMeier edited the code. See the thing is, I have few separate projects and I just need a way to create a pom which will perform "mvn clean install" on each of them one by one.
And those projects have different parents so I can't create a parent child Pom realation. I need to know how can I implement aggregator pom in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034544/how-to-structure-a-multi-modules-maven-project-to-compile-it-at-once/55411236#55411236
similar problem but I dont have parent-child hierarchy in my situation...